# Templated functions in templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, expression-templates

I am constructing a library that makes use of expression templates, where I make heavily use of templated functions in classes. All my code is running and recently I decided to make the main class templated to allow for using it on data of different kinds. However, I can no longer specialize my functions. How do I solve this? I have attached a small test program that shows the problem.

My previous `Animal` class was not templated and then this code works fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

// Example templated class with templated function
template<class T>
class Animals
{
  public:
    template<class X>
    void printFood(const X& x) const { std::cout << "We eat " << x << "!" << std::endl; }

  private:
    std::vector<T> animals;
};

// How do I specialize?
template<class T> template<>
void Animals<T>::printFood(const unsigned int& x) const { std::cout << "We don't want to eat " << x << "!" << std::endl; }

// Main loop;
int main()
{
  Animals<double> doubleAnimals;

  const int banana = 42;
  doubleAnimals.printFood(banana);

  const unsigned int apple = 666;
  doubleAnimals.printFood(apple);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't specialize functions, overload them. Here is an excellent article by Herb Sutter: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: The problem with expression templates is that the potential list of types is infinite, how do I deal with overloading then?

Comment: depends. How does the infinite list of types looks like?

Comment: So construct types from a tree that describes one calculation, so 
`a + b + c + d` would be the type `sum<d, sum<c, sum<b, a> > >` etc. etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simply isn't possible

[temp.expl.spec]

> 16 In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that **the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.**

Comment: Well, this summarizes it very well. -1 for my design then.

Answer (score 2):

You should specialize your class first. Then specialize function:

```
template<> template<>
void Animals<double>::printFood(const unsigned int& x) const { std::cout << "We don't want to eat " << x << "!" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: But I do not want to specialize my class first, because then I end up writing an infinite number of specializations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially specialize template members of non-specialized template class. This is consistent with prohibiting partial specialization of template functions (think of template class as the member function's first parameter). Use overloading instead:

```
template<class T>
class Animals
{
public:
    template<class X>
    void printFood(const X& x) const { std::cout << "We eat " << x << "!" << std::endl; }

    void printFood(const unsigned int& x) const { std::cout << "We don't want to eat " << x << "!" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::vector<T> animals;
};
```

Comment: he wasn't partially specializing the function. The problem is that you can't specialize a function of a non-specialized templated class.

Comment: @bolov It's basically the same: you can consider `void Animal<T>::printFood(X) const` as `void printFood(const Animal<T>&, X)`, so you must specialize either both parameters or none.

Comment: Is writing a templated and a non-templated version of the same function still considered overloading?

Comment: I have put a new question concerning that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168290/is-a-templated-and-a-nontemplated-version-of-the-same-function-considered-an-ove