# Is a templated and a nontemplated version of the same function considered an overload?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization

A very formal question: is this considered an overload? Is removing the template fundamentally different than only overloading on arguments?

```
template<class T> void myFunction(const T& t) {}
void myFunction(const double& t) {}
```

Then the follow up question, is it better to follow this approach or to use template specialization, instead of the overload?

```
template<> void myFunction(const double& t) {}
```

Comment: Have you read [the article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) suggested to you by @bolov in the previous question?

Comment: I did, but I thought it would be good to have this clear on SO, I miss the answer to the second part of the question. In case I do not want to specialize my main template, which is the preferred way to go? I thought this discussion deserved its own question.

Comment: I doubt that SO can add much to Herb's discussion. There's a good summary under "Important Morals".

Comment: @AntonSavin ty for making it possible for me to basically upvote my own comment :)

Comment: @molbdnilo The point I think is not necessarily to bring something new, but to bring that information into Stack Overflow.

Comment: @molbdnilo. At least syntax highlighting. So to make sure that I understand the article correctly: overloading only refers to the function name? So within an overload it can be either templated or non-templated, but not specialized?

Comment: "specializations don't participate in overloading"'

Comment: @AntonSavin The article is interesting, but the motivation it gives for the rule does involve a rather exotic case, not very likely to occur in well written code.  (On the other hand, I still prefer the non-template overload for purely stylistic reasons.)

Comment: I really hate the "the information should be captured in an SO answer" idea, if the canonical reference is Herb's article then that is what people should go to, not an answer on SO that paraphrases it

Comment: @JonathanWakely I disagree with this. In that case, print out the standard and buy the relevant text books, study them in all detail, and all questions can be solved, some rare exceptions there. Most of us, however, do not have the time or background to go that far.

The purpose of every FAQ is to find a quick solution to a very frequently occuring problem. I see it as time optimization. I am a scientist that has to deliver code. C++ is my tool, not my goal.

Comment: @Chiel, I'm talking about a hyperlink to another online reference, how is printing out the standard and buying text books relevant? SO wants to be the canonical source because they get more hits and make more advertising money that way, but that doesn't mean I have to agree and support their business model. Reading Herb's article is better than taking the view that if it's not on SO it might as well not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, according to the standard (start of §13): “When two
or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the
same scope, that name is said to be overloaded.[...]Only function and
function template declarations can be overloaded; variable and type
declarations cannot be overloaded.”  So clearly, your two
declarations are overloads.

If you call `myFunction( 3.14159 )`, then the template will be
instantiated with the same signature as the non-template, and both will
be exact matches.  In this case (§13.3.1):

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments
>   i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and
>   then
>   [...]
>   — F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template
>   specialization,  [...]

The standard has specified your exact case.

With regards to the alternative of specializing the function:
specializations may be overloads according to the definition above, but
they do not participate in overload resolution.  Specializations work
differently: overload resolution first occurs without them; then, if
overload resolution has chosen the template, and there is a
specialization for the instantiation type(s), the specialization is
used, rather than the generic instantiation of the template.  Generally
speaking, the results are the same, although
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm points out one exotic (and
badly written?) case where they aren't.  Still, to me at least, it seems
more natural to provide the overloaded function, rather than the
template specialization.  Most of the time, anyway.  (There is one real
exception: it's sometimes useful to not provide a generic
implementation, but only specializations.  In my experience, this
situation usually occurs with traits classes, but it can occur for an
individual function as well.  In such cases, of course, you do
specialize the template; you cannot use it otherwise.)